# Is it possible to call methods of class dynamically using an object property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, chatbot

I'm working on a bot scope and it works using menus. To each menu, I call a designated function, and depending on the function, I need to treat the input in different ways. Sometimes I have to use "toLowerCase," or sometimes remove diacritics, etc. With that in mind and trying to avoid the use of lots of if-else, I created an object that contains these menus, and they are objects with properties that specify which treatment I should use and which method of the other class I should call. However, I am encountering some issues when calling the method.

```
function processUserInput(input: string, menuIndex: string) {
      const menuIndexMapping: MenuIndexMapping = {
        starting: {
          method: "processUserOptions",
          toLowerCase: true,
          removeAccents: true,
          removeSpecialChars: true,
          replaceSpacesWithUnderscores: true,
        }, 
//...
const menuItem = menuIndexMapping[menuIndex];

      if (menuItem) {
        let processedUserMessage = input;

        if (menuItem.toLowerCase) {
          processedUserMessage = processedUserMessage.toLowerCase();
        }

       //...

        return { processedUserMessage, method: menuItem.method };
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid menuIndex:", menuIndex);
        return;
      }
    }
```

Then, I receive:

```
Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
const result: {
    processedUserMessage: string;
    method: string;
} | undefined
```

If I try:

```
if (conversationStatus === "active") {
      const result = processUserInput(userMessage, menuIndex);

      await this.botMessageController[result?.method](
        result?.processedUserMessage,
        userId,
        menuIndex,
        conversation2.id,
        errorsCounter
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Bot muted");
      return;
    }
```

And if I remove the "?" I'll receive:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BotMessageController'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BotMessageController'.ts(7053)
(property) WebhookController.botMessageController: BotMessageController
```

Is there a way to fix that or other approach I can take to avoid something like:

```
else if (menuIndex === "option_1") {
        const normalizedUserMessage = userMessage
          .normalize("NFD")
          .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s_]/gi, "")
          .replace(/\s+/g, "_");

        await this.botMessageController.handleOption1(
          normalizedUserMessage,
          userId,
          menuIndex,
          conversation2.id,
          errorsCounter
        );
      } else if (menuIndex === "registration_yes") {
        const normalizedUserMessage = userMessage
          .normalize("NFD")
          .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s_]/gi, "");

        await this.botMessageController.handleRegistrationYesOptions(
          normalizedUserMessage,
          userId,
          menuIndex,
          conversation2.id,
          errorsCounter
        );
      }
```

I have searched ways to implement that and correct the error, I also tried to put different typing, tried some suggestions, but I wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: As far as the first message, `Undefined can't be used as an index`, it is because `result` could be undefined. You could add a block above it like `if (!result) return`. For the second, you are setting `result.method` to a string, `method: "processUserOptions",`, then trying to call it as a function, `await this.botMessageController[result?.method](result?.processedUserMessage, ...)`. You should either set it to be a function or not call it depending what you're trying to do.

Comment: `console.log("Invalid menuIndex:", menuIndex); return;` Throw an error here instead, then it won't be `undefined` (or `return undefined as never`)